# What to do about this gnome-keyring message?

Tags: 12.04, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get this warning from Gnome keyring in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243210/why-do-i-get-this-warning-from-gnome-keyring-in-xubuntu)

I upgraded from ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 and installed lxde. Since then whenever I try to print some file (or use command `lpstat`), I get this message on the terminal:

> "WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to:
>   /tmp/keyring-SZ59jJ/pkcs11:  No such file or directory".

This is beyond my knowledge and from search I only realize that this may be related to security (as learned from [GNOME Keyring on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring)). I have no idea what to do about this warning. Can anybody please suggest? Evidently as stated, I am not using gnome desktop, I choose lxde session at the time of logging in.

Answer (score -1):

Try running `lpstat` as `root` with `sudo`.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo lpstat <filename>
```

Comment: I think you missed the question: lpstat will not help with the gnome-keyring message.