# Why do I get this warning from Gnome keyring in Xubuntu?

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, git, gnome-keyring

I have installed xubuntu-desktop ontop of a stock Ubuntu installation.

When using ssh, or more specifically git, I always get this warning

```
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-IVaeDO/pkcs11: No such file or directory
```

I have done a fair amount of googling to disable/enable the proper services at boot time, but so far I always end up with this error.

Any insight on completely removing gnome-keyring, and it's downfalls, OR integrating gnome-keyring into xubuntu/xfce would be awesome.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You get this warning because gnome services such as `gnome-keyring-daemon` and `gnome-settings-daemon` are not normally running when you are logged into a Xubuntu or Xfce session.

However, the quick fix that has worked for me is to go to the menu and choose settings > settings manager > session and startup > advanced and enable Gnome services (see screenshot below). Now, all installed Gnome services will start when you login, and you should be able to use the functionality of `gnome-keyring-daemon` (although further configuration may be necessary, as I note below).

[image]

It is important to note that you will have to logout and login again for this to take effect, and then services such as these will be running (if you have already have installed them with gnome applications):

[image]

You may need to tweak other things in the Xfce/Xubuntu session, depending on how you wish to use `gnome-keyring-daemon`. There are some references to using it with [ssh on this blog](http://lekv.de/blog/tag/xfce/) and many others out there, but there can be problems to overcome with using it on Xubuntu.

It is too big of a topic to produce a general answer on the pros and cons of `gnome-keyring`, but these hints should enable you to begin integrating it into a Xubuntu session.

However, if these suggestions don't solve the problem, you may be a victim of the problem described at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1022322) regarding `gnome-keyring`.

Comment: Thanks, Any tips on how to go the other direction and remove all gnome stuff and still have ssh-agent and ssh-add run at boot?

Comment: @winchendonsprings `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` are part of the `openssh-client` package, which doesn't depend on any gnome applications or services, so it might be possible, but I'm not sure on this.

Comment: what version of ubuntu is this for? Don't see all this options on 12.04 LTS

Comment: @sureshvv Xubuntu 12.04 and later; the options are definitely available in Xubuntu 12.04. Go to settings > settings manager > Session and Startup > Advanced.

Comment: @Mik What is the command for displaying that box? I would like to try this on Fluxbox.

Comment: @rvf0068 `xfce4-session-settings` will launch the box from the command line without going through the menus.

Comment: Is it required to log out/in of the session for this setting to be effective? I changed the setting then ssh'ed to the box, and still get the same error. This is Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 30):

Under a Bourne shell, you can turn off gnome-keyring and get rid of this warning by running:

```
unset GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
```

to remove the gnome keyring path from your environment variables. You can also put this command at the end of your ~/.bashrc file.

Under a C shell, the equivalent command is:

```
unsetenv GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
```

and the command can be put at the end of your ~/.cshrc file.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get rid of that pesky warning (I got this in XFCE):

The trick is to add "`LXDE;XFCE;`" on the line with `OnlyShowIn=` (without the double quotes and plus the semicolon, didn't try without it) to this file "`/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop`"  by editing it with whatever text editor you prefer, I'll use "nano"

1 - in a terminal type (as root or with sudo):

```
# nano /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Certificate and Key Storage
Comment=GNOME Keyring: PKCS#11 Component
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;LXDE;XFCE;
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-keyring
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.2
NoDisplay=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-keyring
```

2 - after editing, make sure you save the changes

3 - restart computer.

Answer (score 0):

Both sound a great anwser but both did'nt work for me
[image]

**[UPDATED] : To make it work**

as root, I made the file /usr/share/gnome/autostart/seahorse-daemon.desktop
[image: Edit seahorse-daemon]

And be sure **AT-SPI D-Bus Bus** is ON into my autostart.

For those have an error like that :

> Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-sFJMjhBCfL: Connection refused

It's might be more an issue with your /tmpfs than
with seahorse-daemon or gnome-keyring

Now let's figure how to replace seahorse-agent! :)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and apply code formatting instead.