# gnome-keyring error sending email in mutt

Tags: gnome, keyrings, mutt

here is my `.msmtprc` :

```
defaults  
account gmail  
host smtp.gmail.com    
from yy@gmail.com  
port 587  
auth on  
tls on  
tls_starttls on  
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  

user yy@gmail.com  
password xxxxxxxx  
logfile ~/.msmtp.log    
account default:gmail

here is my  /etc/Muttrc  
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"   
set use_from=yes   
set realname="xxxx"   
set from="yy@gmail.com"  
set envelope_from=yes  
set charset="utf-8"  
set send_charset="utf-8"  
set locale="zh_CN.UTF-8"  
set content_type="text/html\;charset=utf-8"
```

When I input:

```
echo "test" | mutt -s "subject"  xxxxx@163.com  
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /home/debian/.cache/keyring-HF6INk/pkcs11: No such file or directory
```

What is the matter?

Comment: As to why you get the above error, see [my answer for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243210/why-do-i-get-this-warning-from-gnome-keyring-in-xubuntu).